# What's the difference between `puts` and `return` result?

Tags: ruby

When I run the following code:

```
class GermanShepard
  attr_accessor :name
  def bark
    puts "Loud Bark"
  end
end

max = GermanShepard.new
max.name = "Max"
puts "#{max.name} goes #{max.bark}"
```

the result is:

```
Loud Bark
Max goes
```

When I change `puts` to `return` at the `GermanShepard`. It gives:

```
Max goes Loud Bark
```

I don't understand the difference between the two command in the class.

Comment: I really appreciate you guys kind explanation and it helps a lot to me. And more depth of understanding Ruby language. Happy New Year all of you!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Expression

In most languages, `return` in a method means giving a value to the caller.

In Ruby, everything is an [expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_(computer_science)). In an essence, the last line of a method is automatically called with `return`. As an example, the following methods are equivalent:

```
def bark_a
    'Woof!'
end

def bark_b
    return 'Woof!'
end
```

However, some methods may not be `return`ing anything.

```
def bark_c
end
```

In this case, ruby is actually returning a `nil` object. An example would be the

`puts` method. The `puts` method simply displays whatever you've given it.

So in your example,

```
def bark
  puts "Loud Bark"
end
```

is actually doing 2 things.

1. It's calling the `puts` method (displaying `Loud Bark` to the terminal screen)
2. then it's giving a `nil` value back to the method caller.

You can try running `puts nil` and see what's printed out!

### "#{}"

Calling `#{}` in ruby is called [interpolation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Interpolation), which is basically putting the variables together in their closest `string` representation value. The following statements are roughly equivalent:

```
puts "One plus one equals #{1 + 1}"
puts "One plus one equals " + (1 + 1).to_s
```

### Your example

With all the information above, we can now go through your example step-by-step.

The line `puts "#{max.name} goes #{max.bark}"` can be separated into a few steps

1. Calls the `name` method
2. The value `return`ed is converted into the closest `string` representation (In this case we don't need to do anything since `name` is already a `string`)
3. The value is then saved to a temporary variable

At this point, our temporary variable is `Max goes`.

4. Calls the `bark` method
5. The line `puts "Loud Bark"` gets executed since we're calling it in the `bark` method.
6. Terminal(console) displays "Loud Bark"
7. Since the `puts` method returns a `nil` value, the `bark` method is also going to `return` a `nil` value because it's the last line of the `bark` method. (Read "Expression" above)
8. `nil` is then converted to the closest `string` representation (which is "")
9. It is then saved to a temporary variable

The temporary variable is now `Max goes`

10. Now, the temporary variable is passed into the `puts` method, and the terminal(console) displays "Max goes "
11. Program finishes

Therefore, your example prints out

```
Loud Bark
Max goes
```

However, if we change the `puts` inside the `bark` method to `return`,

Step 6 will not happen.
Instead of `return`ing a `nil` value in step 7, it will `return` `"Load bark"`
Step 8 will not happen since `"Loud bark"` already a `string` value
and the temporary value after step 9 will become `Max goes Loud bark`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

`puts(string)` in ruby writes the string value into `$stdout`. For example if you run ruby console in terminal, string will be written into your terminal. At the same time every method in ruby returns something and method `puts` returns `nil`. So, when we want to interpolate string like "Hello #{some_method}" it will interpolate a returning value of `some_method`, in case of `puts` it will interpolate `nil` value.

```
Loud Bark # output of max.bark method
Max goes # output of last puts
```

Comment: Could you expand your answer to explain the example in the question?

Answer (score 1):

Ray's answer is probably correct, but since it is too verbose (and I didn't even feel like reading it), I will post a concise answer.

---

There are two things to have in mind.

1. All arguments passed to a method are evaluated prior to the method call.
2. All methods in Ruby have a return value. In addition, some methods have side effect, an example of which is to output on the terminal. In any case, returning a value is done after a method has done all its side effects.

With your code as is, the argument of `puts` in

```
puts "#{max.name} goes #{max.bark}"
```

is first evaluated. In order to do so, `max.bark` (among other things like `max.name`) would have to be evaluated in advance. The method `bark` prints `"Loud Bark"`, then returns `nil`. So the argument mentioned above becomes `"#{"Max"} goes #{nil}"`, and eventually to `"Max goes "`. That is printed after `"Loud Bark"`.

When you change the `puts` in the method to `return`, the method `bark` will have no side effect, and returns `"Loud Bark"`; that is the function of `return` (and by the way, `return` is not a method but is a keyword). So the argument mentioned above becomes `"#{"Max"} goes #{"Loud Bark"}"`, and eventually to `"Max goes Loud Bark"`. That would be the only thing printed.

Answer (score 0):

```
puts "Loud Bark"   # => returns nil
return "Loud Bark" # => returns "Loud Bark"
```